# Shader graph in Oculus (Screen position)

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I have created a blur shader graph to blur a material. It works perfectly fine in the scene mode and also in windows application. However it does not work as expected in Oculus VR. That is, the texture in the material shakes/moves with the camera. I am aware that the problem would be with screen position node with tiling and offset since the Oculus works differently. Has anyone faced this issue and found a solution?

EDIT: It is related to rendering issue. Oculus Quest has multi-pass rendering so the left eye works fine but the right eye has issues. Any solution?

[image: Blur shader graph]

Comment: Have you tried setting the android XR integration settings to multiview?

Comment: Yes, I have tried multi-pass/view yet no luck. It only works for Single-Pass but Oculus Quest does not support it.